# How to specify install directory for requirements.txt for each dependency; NOT install all requirements in one directory

Tags: python-3.x

We have a repository of lambda functions. Each lambda functions may have its own set of dependencies. As part of CI/CD pipeline, we want to install the appropriate dependencies in the appropriate folder.

Is there a way to manage dependencies across multiple install locations from one text file?

Comment: If each lambda has its own set of dependencies, it makes most sense for each of them to have their own `requirements.txt`

Comment: @rdas That does make sense. That is what we are doing. But now we want to integrate a pipeline and instead of working with dozens of `requirements.txt` files, I was thinking it might be easier to have one file and for each dependency in that file to specify which folder it should go in. This seems like functionality that is out of scope for `pip install` though.

Comment: Not a good idea. Pretty soon when your different projects start depending on different versions  of the same dependency you'll be regretting that decision. Follow the KISS principle.